# Codeigniter generic model functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I am still wondering why CodeIgniter just don't provide generic functions for model which can be generally usefull for creating reading update deleting joining and other manipulation of records to provide facility to the user and save time of the developer i have read about the [Grocery CRUD](http://www.grocerycrud.com/) but it is not that what i am looking for i have created two three function which you can call generic functions for retrieving and updating.
Here the functions are.

1. ***get_records***

*returns multiple records*

```
function get_records($table, $where=NULL)
    {
        if(!empty($where))
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $query=$this->db->get($table);
        if($query->num_rows>0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
```

2. get_record()

*return single record*

```
function get_record($table, $where=NULL)
    {
        if(!empty($where))
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $query=$this->db->get($table);
        if($query->num_rows>0)
        {
            return $query->row();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

3. Update()

   general purpose function for updation

   ```
   function update($table ,$where=NULL ,$data)
   {
       if(!empty($where))
       {
           $this->db->where($where);
       }
       $query=$this->db->update($table,$data);
       if($query)
       {
           return $this->db->affected_rows();
       }

   }
   ```
4. delete()

//general purpose function for deletion

```
function delete($table , $where=NULL)
    {
        if(!empty($where))
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        if($this->db->delete($table))
        {
            return $this->db->affected_rows();
        }
    }
```

Here are my general function but There is alot more to do with CodeIgniter model because there are alot of functions which can be created as generic functions

My question is do any body have already derived this kind of stuff if yes provide me the link i have been looking for generic functions for CodeIgniter Model because if someone so it would be more time saving rather than writing one by our own

***But in www do any body created generic functions for CodeIgniter model?***

Comment: But in www do any body created generic functions for CodeIgniter model? this is what i am asking bro its not too broad if some one have made library for generic functions it will provide link and it will be helpful for other user as for me

Answer (score 2):

I am not very active in the CodeIgniter community anymore but the one that I used in the past is here

https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

If you are looking to inject an ORM into CodeIgniter, perhaps you may want to look at this quick tutorial:

http://jamieonsoftware.com/post/90299647695/using-eloquent-orm-inside-codeigniter-with-added-query

Comment: i appreciated but still looking for the good one

Comment: http://xkcd.com/927/

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgnite community has stopped updating the framework. I am not aware but i would suggest group of developers who can work on CI and make generic tools for CI. I am interested to be part of such groups

Comment: and me too! send me your email address so we can create such generic functions togather

Comment: mohammad.arif.fast@hotmail.com @AitazazKhan

Comment: waiting @AitazazKhan

Comment: sorry buddy i have been busy in huge project i am going to contact you right now